# Why is a UILabel not appearing in a subView?

Tags: uiview, uilabel

I have created a class Word1View that is a subclass of UIView. In it I have a UILabel testLabel that is a property and has been properly synthesized in the .m file.
Here's the .h file.

```
@interface Word1View : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *testLabel;
@end
```

The property word1View of type Word1View was created in interface builder and added to my storyboard and has been added as a property to my main view controller:

```
@interface Board3ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet Word1View *word1View;

@end
```

and has been properly connected as an IBOutlet.

In the viewDidLoad method of my view controller is the following code:

```
word1View.testLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10)];
word1View.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
word1View.testLabel.text = @"Working?";
[self.view addSubview:word1View];
NSLog(@"Label text is: %@", word1View.testLabel.text);
```

Now I know that all this code is working since the subview changes it's background color and the testLabel gets the correct text since it's printed out by the NSLog statement.  The problem is that the UILabel testLabel DOES NOT APPEAR when the program is run?  I have tried setNeedsDisplay and that doesn't help.
Any help is gratefully appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: Are you setting the text property on the main thread?

Comment: The text is correctly written by the NSLog statement so it is getting set correctly

Comment: I see a `UILabel` property of `Word1View`, but where are you setting the instance of that label as a subview of `word1View`?

Comment: Pls also provide info about your Word1View, what are the frame attribs of that view? Maybe u place label outside of the bounds of its superview..

Comment: @Gil Trying to make UI changes on a background thread does not (always) behave properly.  That being said, `-viewDidLoad` will be called on the main thread.

Comment: I have to add the label as a subView of word1View?

Comment: @Gil Yes.  Currently, instances of `Word1View` happen to have a property that happens to be of type `UILabel`.  The `UILabel` will not automatically become a subview of `word1View`.

Comment: Unless the label has been added to the view in interface builder, yes, you will need to add it as a subview. The class has `UILabel` property but that doesn't mean that that `UILabel` is rendered anywhere on the view.

Comment: On a different note, the line `[self.view addSubview:word1View];` (probably) does not need to be there, assuming that in Interface Builder you placed the Word1View instance within your view controller's view.  (If you placed the `Word1View` outside of any other view, then you do need to call `-addSubview:`, but doing that is quite non-standard.)

Comment: All credit goes to @AntP.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, add the label as a subview to the `world1View` object. If you want this to appear by default, you could do this in the initializer of `World1View`:

```
-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.testLabel = [[UILabel alloc]
            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 10)];
        self.testLabel.text = @"Working?";
        [self addSubview: self.testLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Apologies for any errors in the above code - my Objective-C syntax still isn't very sharp. Should communicate the message, though!